# Write $100$ as sum of $n$ numbers, such that each number is twice as big as its predecessor.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I don't quite know where to start on this one.

lets say we have a value 100.
and we want to split it in two parts where one is twice as big as the other.

That would be $v_1 = 66.666$ and $v_2= 33.333$ (sum $100$)

If we want to split the value in 3 parts, where each part is twice as big as the others.

That would be $v_1 = 57.15$ , $v_2 = 28.58$, $v_3 = 14.29 $(sum $100$)

What do I need to do to get $66.66$ from $2$ and $57.15$ from $3$ and so on?

Comment: I took the liberty to edit title and tag, since - as Arkamis has pointed out - this is not about _logarithms_.

Comment: Three answers have been posted so far, and I, who have not answered, am the only person who's up-voted the question so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with logarithms, but rather to do with simultaneous equations.

In the first case, you want to find two values that sum to 100:

$$x + y = 100.$$

You also have the second condition that one is double the other:

$$x = 2y.$$

You can combine these equations to get

$$ x + y = 2y + y = 3y = 100 \implies y = \frac{100}{3}, x = 2 \cdot \frac{100}{3}.$$

In your second case, you have three numbers:

$$x + y + z = 100,$$

where each number is twice the previous,

$$x = 2y, \\
y = 2z.$$

Again, you can solve these simultaneous equations:

$$x = 2y = 2(2z) = 4z, \\
x + y + z = 4z + 2z + z = 7z = 100 \implies z = \frac{100}{7} = 14.\overline{285714}.$$

Answer (score 4):

Usually, it helps to formalize the problem. You are looking for an $a$, such that
$$\begin{align}v_1&=a\\ v_2&=2v_1=2a\\ v_3&=2v_2=4a\\ \vdots \\ v_n&=2^{n-1}a\end{align}$$
and $v_1+\dots+v_n=100$, which is the same as 
$$100=a+2a+4a+\dots+2^{n-1}a$$
See, if you can go on from here. The [formula for geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Geometric_series) might help.

Answer (score 0):

Arkasim's answer made me realize it can be written as:

split 1 :
1x = 1x = 100

split 2 :
2x + 1x = 3x = 100

split 3 :
4x + 2x + 1x = 7x = 100

split 4 :
8x + 4x + 2x + 1x = 15x = 100

x = 100 / (2^(s-1)*2-1)

where s is the number of splits.